# LAN filetransfer over switch - router (dhcp, dns) offline

Tags: networking, router, dns, dhcp

**Scenario:** I am copying e.g. 1TB files with "rsync" from one machine to another (both get's dynmaic IPs). Between this two computers there are three switches. On one switch there is a router connected which makes the connection to the modem and runs the DHCP and DNS server for my LAN.

**Question:** Will the copying-task get's canceled if the router goes offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if the traffic doesn't flow through the router. Assuming that both endpoints of the transfer are on the same layer-2 domain and layer-3 subnet, and the connections between the switches between the endpoints do not go through the router. The router is not used, and it is peripheral and unnecessary to this traffic flow.

Comment: Answer may not be correct, though.  In all likelihood, it is.  However, it may not be.  The transfer could be aborted IF the DHCP lease expires and the offline router is unable to renew it in time.  (Likelihood of that would depend on multiple factors, like just how much data is being copied.  In most cases, this ought to be fine, but not necessarily.)